# how can i insert a variable in to a href value in a link in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

i have:

```
  <a href="/patients/#{@appointment.patient.id}">
  <%=h @appointment.patient.f_name %> <%=h @appointment.patient.l_name%>
  </a>
```

but it dose not work due to a syntax error, if i click on the href it goes to `http://0.0.0.0:3000/patients/#{@appointment.patient.id}`

thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do:

```
<a href="/patients/<%= @appointment.patient.id %>">
```

But it's generally easier to use `link_to`:

```
link_to(@appointment.patient.f_name + " " + @appointment.patient.l_name, 
        :controller => 'patients', :action => 'show', :id => @appointment.patient.id)
```