# Sinatra App Not Using Erb in Links

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

The problem I'm having is that Sinatra apps don't always seem to show my ERB when it is used in some specific context of hyperlinks. I have no idea how much is relevant to show for this question, so I'll do the best I can .Basically, I have a file in my Sinatra app called book_show.erb. It has the following line:

```
<p><a href="/books/#{@book.id}/edit">Edit Book</a></p>
```

However, when that link is rendered in the browser, it links like this:

```
http://localhost:9292/books/#{@book.id}/edit
```

The #{@book.id} was not replaced with the actual ID value. There is a @book object and I do use it in other contexts in that very same file. For example:

```
<h1><%= @book.series %></h2>
<h2><%= @book.title %></h2>

<h3>Timeframe:</h3>
<p><%= @book.timeframe %></p>
```

I don't even know if my routes would make a difference here for diagnosing this but all of the relevant routes for my books functionality are:

```
get '/books' do
  @title = 'Book Database'
  @books = Book.all
  erb :books
end

get '/books/new' do
  @book = Book.new
  erb :book_add
end

get '/books/:id' do
  @book = Book.get(params[:id])
  erb :book_show
end

post '/books' do
  book = Book.create(params[:book])
  redirect to("/books/#{book.id}")
end
```

I don't know what else to show to help diagnose this problem. I'm hoping someone sees something terribly obvious that I'm missing.

Adding a book to the database works just fine; it's only that edit link that I can't get to work correctly -- and that would seem to be pure HTML/ERB. In order to test it, I also added this line to the page:

```
<p>Testing: <%= "/books/#{@book.id}/edit" %>
```

That came back and returned this text:

```
Testing: /books/4/edit
```

So I know the ID is getting stored. It has to be something to do with the hyperlink but I can find nothing useful on Sinatra that helps at all with this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i insert a variable in to a href value in a link in rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367776/how-can-i-insert-a-variable-in-to-a-href-value-in-a-link-in-rails)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ERB template does not behave like a ruby string - you need to explicitly tell it you exit the 'template' part into the 'logic' part. It looks very odd when it comes to attributes:

```
<p><a href="/books/<%= @book.id %>/edit">Edit Book</a></p>
```

You could use `link_to` helpers to make it look better:

```
link_to('Edit Book', controller: 'books', action: 'edit', id: @book.id)
```

Comment: The `link_to` helper is from Rails and isn’t available in Sinatra (unless you write your own).

Comment: Thank you for this. Your change did the trick. I'm curious why this linked file then seems to work, which I modeled by own logic off of:

https://github.com/spbooks/SINATRA1/blob/master/chapter06/views/show_song.slim

Comment: @JeffNyman that page is using [Slim](http://slim-lang.com/), not ERB, and Slim does use Ruby interpolation like syntax.

Comment: @matt Ah! Thank you. I did realize the Slim vs. ERB difference but I didn't realize how that may impact other things. That alone may explain why I've been having a lot of issues with some Sinatra tutorials. (Some use HAML, some use ERB, some use Slim.)